# Ensuring the user is logged in

Tags: php, validation, session, authentication

I am trying to redirect the user to my login page if the user is not logged in.

This variable is created when the user enters a successful login

```
$_SESSION['loggedin'] == true;
    header("location:mainpage.php");
```

on my 'mainpage' this is my code:

```
if($_SESSION['loggedin'] == false)
    header("location:login.php");
```

I have added 'Session_start();' to the top of both pages also
My current problem is that everytime I login I am automatically redirected back to my login page so this is clearly not working

Comment: try === with object operator

Comment: @mahen3d same problem still persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a comparison instead of assign `true` to the variable. Try to do this:

```
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
header("location:mainpage.php");
```

Comment: Thank you! Very simple mistake of me to make